# Hydra + Tamper http post form syntax of the failure login attempt

Tags: php, http, ajax

I am doing a pentest of an internal site. I would like to check how secure is this when using Hydra as the password cracking tool.

I have used the Mozilla Tamper add-on to get the HEAD options (I think I do not have the correct ones)

What I tried:

- `user=tech15` (technical user, users are known)
- List of passwords where only ONE is the correct one = `fakelist.txt`

  `hydra -l tech15 -P fakelist.txt -vV www.mysite.com http-post-form "/members-login.php=:user^USER^&pass=^PASS^:S="`

The string `/auth/ajax-login-frame.php?ajax-login-frame-id=register-or-login-overlay-ajax-login-frame&usernameAttempt=tech15`  is the failure page, when password is not correct and it tells you  the user has tried to login.

When successfully logged in, the page is redirected to another page.

`/members-login.php` is the webpage

and the tamper just provided me with the following string, where the last part of the user attempt is not written

```
/auth/ajax-login-frame.php?ajax-login-frame-id=register-or-login-overlay-ajax-login-frame
```

I wonder if the information from tamper I have collected is correct, or I need to look after again.

Could you please help me to understand how to describe properly the syntax for a successful login?

When executing the commands in hydra, all passwords from the list (99 passwords) are valid, which is not correct and only ONE is the valid one.

```
[80][www-form] host: ip.number.X.XX  login: tech15   password: notcorrect
[STATUS] attack finished for www.mysite.com (waiting for
children to complete tests)
1 of 1 target successfully completed, 99 valid passwords found
```

### When Failing

```
http://www.mysite.com/auth/ajax-login-frame.php?ajax-login-frame-id=register-or-login-overlay-ajax-login-frame&usernameAttempt=tech15
```

### When Successful

```
http://www.mysite.com/auth/ajax-login-success.php?ajax-login-frame-id=register-or-login-overlay-ajax-login-frame

Cookie=PHPSESSID=9c77p1nhj530mpj4apun1mjv71;
```

But I still get all 99 paswords as valid ones.

Comment: Have you tried typing `man hydra`?

Comment: Yes, it is not explaining the failure syntax

Comment: With Fiddler, check what comes back when doing a successful login, and compare it to what comes back when doing an unsuccessful one. Fill in the difference as a S= or F= parameter. Also check the headers and use the H= parameter to reproduce them. If it is still failing youll have to compare a web app resuest to a hydra request with Wireshark.

Comment: It is long winded as `man hydra` indicates that you can use `hydra -h` for help, then the output from this shows you can get specific module help with `-U` including failure syntax: `hydra -U http-post-form`.

Comment: I have still the problem, I do not understand how the get the proper information with Tamper. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Manual:

- -v -V: be verbose
- -L: user list
- -P: password list
- -l: username
- -p: password
- -s: server + port
- “1:2:3:4”: 1=page, 2=body content, 3=failure (F=) or success (S=) message, 4: H= headers can be specified (optional). In headers, you do not have to escape the colon.

So, what you should do is add something next to the `S=` you have there. That something should be a word that appears on the page to which your site is redirecting after successful login (e.g. success, welcome, etc.). Something like this:

```
hydra -l tech15 -P fakelist.txt -vV www.mysite.com http-post-form "/members-login.php=:user^USER^&pass=^PASS^:S=Welcome"
```

Of course, if you have a specific failure page (e.g. "login failed"), you could just replace the `S=` with `F=` and add `F=failed`